# ansible: 'default' filter that treats the empty string as not defined

Tags: ansible

If I do this:

```
- set_fact:
    NEW_VARIABLE: "{{ VARIABLE | default('default') }}"
```

and `VARIABLE` is the empty string (`""`), than the default not triggering.

I could do this:

```
- set_fact:
    NEW_VARIABLE: "{{ VARIABLE | default('default') }}"
- set_fact:
    NEW_VARIABLE: "default"
   when: VARIABLE == ""
```

But I actually want to do this in a loop. So it would be much easier if I could do this using ansible filters and not conditionals.

Is this possible? Are there ansible filters that work like `default` but treats `""` as not defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, its possible.

Dont know if its something like that you want but, for your description, this will work for you...

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    VARIABLE: ""
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        NEW_VARIABLE: '{{ (VARIABLE |length > 0) | ternary(VARIABLE, "default") }}'
    - debug: msg="{{ NEW_VARIABLE }}"
```

> ```
> PLAY [localhost] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
>
> TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
> ok: [localhost]
>
> TASK [set_fact] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
> ok: [localhost]
>
> TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
> ok: [localhost] => {
>     "msg": "default"
> }
> ```

Im assuming that your variable will always be defined as `""`. By assuming that, its possible check its length and then use the ternary filter. If its bigger than 0, it use the variable value and if not, it will set `NEW_VARIABLE` to `"default"`. If you dont know if `VARIABLE` will be defined or not, put a `when: VARIABLE is defined` on your `set_fact` task and this should be it.

Source: [Ansible filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html)

Answer (score 38):

You have to set second argument of default to `true`

```
{{ VARIABLE | default('default', true) }}
```

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#defaulting-undefined-variables

Comment: This is the most elegant and comes right from the official docs.